# openSSH is ignoring the HOME env variable

Tags: cygwin, openssh, passwd

I've been trying to sort out the `Could not create directory` issue with openSSH installed via cygwin, and have tried every *solution* I can find on the internet, but none of them are working...

I've installed cygwin, it appears to work. I installed openSSH, which also appears to work (i can ssh into other machines).

I've put the cygwin bin folder in the `path`, so i can run `ssh` fro mthe command line, and that works too. But every time I run it it gives me the error:

```
Could not create directory '/home/will/.ssh'
The authenticity of host 'blah (111.222.333.444)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Why is it trying to use that directory? I have set the env. variable `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%`, it prints the correct location when I echo it, and I also have created the `.ssh` dir and done the `ssh-keygen` thing there.

I read somewhere that i need to replace `home/will` in `cygwin/etc/passwd`, but I don't have that file. And if I use `mkpasswd -l` to generate it it does not include me as a user, so there's nothing I can replace. I'm really stumped.

What do I need to do/set to make this work?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225764/safely-change-home-directory-in-cygwin

Comment: @Chris.C Which answer? my user does not appear in the file created by `mkpasswd`, so how can i edit the home directory provided there?

Answer (score 3):

If you look inside "/usr/bin/ssh-user-config", you will notice the advise:

```
    csih_error_multi \
      "There is no home directory set for you in the account database." \
      'Setting $HOME is not sufficient!'
```

Without touching the Windows user database, the fastest way to define a different home is:

```
 mkpasswd -d -u "Your_Windows_User_Name" > /etc/passwd
or
 mkpasswd -l -u "Your_Windows_User_Name" > /etc/passwd
```

likely "will". As you user is local or is a domain one.

And modify the last but one field "/home/will" with the value you want.

Additional reading, on Windows and Cygwin users:

```
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config and add the following properties:

```
IdentityFile /C/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
UserKnownHostsFile /C/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This still prints the error `Could not create directory '/home/username/.ssh'.` But apart from that everything works. By the way I am using msys2 but theoretically this should work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to matzeri for the hint to look in /usr/bin/ssh-user-conifg.  Looking in there, I realized that the script is getting the home directory via a call to `getent passwd`.  When I run that on my system, I see that the home directory its looking for is in /home (which in the Windows file system translates to C:\Cygwin64\home\myusername)

My actual Windows home directory (%USERDIR%) is C:\Users\myusername, which Cygwin sees as /cygdrive/c/Users/myusername.

I discovered that, as an alternative to creating an /etc/passwd file, I can symlink my Windows home directory to the location Cygwin wants:

```
cd /home
rm -rf myusername
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/myusername .
```

After doing this, SSH has no problem reading the .ssh directory in my Windows home directory.